# Outlook 2013 code that saves attachments depending on what email it was sent to

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I need to automatically save an attachment depending on what email it was sent to (not by senders).

I have 3 emails on the mail server pdf@, xml@, txt@. If email is sent to @pdf I need to save it on a network drive, and same goes for the other emails but to different locations.

All other code I have seen only take into account the sender not the sent to address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created 3x postlists and one rule in Outlook.

When email is sent to (add all the postlists) and has an attachment
run this script. ps. you have to edit all of the paths, foldernames and postlistnames.

```
Sub SaveAllAttachments(objitem As MailItem)

Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
Dim strName, strLocation As String
Dim dblCount, dblLoop As Double

Dim strSub As String
Dim iRcpCount, iRcp As Integer

strLocation = "O:\PDF\"

 On Error GoTo ExitSub
 If objitem.Class = olMail Then
     Set objAttachments = objitem.Attachments
     dblCount = objAttachments.Count
     If dblCount <= 0 Then
         GoTo 100
     End If

    strSub = ""
    iRcpCount = objitem.Recipients.Count
    For iRcp = 1 To iRcpCount
        If objitem.Recipients(iRcp).Name = "Postlist1" Then
            strSub = "Folder1onOdrive"
        ElseIf objitem.Recipients(iRcp).Name = "Postlist2" Then
            strSub = "Folder2onOdrive"
        ElseIf objitem.Recipients(iRcp).Name = "Postlist3" Then
            strSub = "Folder3onOdrive"
        End If

    Next iRcp

    For dblLoop = 1 To dblCount
        strName = objAttachments.Item(dblLoop).FileName
        'strName = strLocation & strName
        strName = strLocation & strSub & strName
        'strName = strLocation & strName
        objAttachments.Item(dblLoop).SaveAsFile strName
    Next dblLoop
    objitem.Delete
End If
100
ExitSub:
Set objAttachments = Nothing
Set objOutlook = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the [ItemSend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865076(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Application class where you can check out the To address (or the Recipients collection) and save the attachment if required. For example:

```
 Public WithEvents myOlApp As Outlook.Application  

 Public Sub Initialize_handler()  
   Set myOlApp = Outlook.Application  
 End Sub 

 Private Sub myOlApp_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean) 
   Dim prompt As String  
   prompt = "Are you sure you want to send " & Item.Subject & "?"  
   If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Sample") = vbNo Then  
     Cancel = True  
   End If  
 End Sub
```

The ItemSend event is fired whenever an Microsoft Outlook item is sent, either by the user through an Inspector (before the inspector is closed, but after the user clicks the Send button) or when the Send method for an Outlook item, such as MailItem, is used in a program.

You may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx) article helpful.